# Is there an alternative to using Visual Studio for the Unreal Engine?

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

A while back I had downloaded the Unreal Engine on my new PC, and ran it. A message popped up saying that I needed Visual Studio installed to use the engine. So I went ahead and downloaded the installer for Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, but upon running it, I was notified that I needed 6GB across all drives. Unfortunately for me, I don't have more than 3GB left on my SSD. Is there an alternative to using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've installed UE4, but as far as I know, you don't need Visual Studio unless you are going to be incorporating C++ into your game.  You're not obligated to use C++, you can make simple games entirely in Blueprint, the visual scripting language of the engine.  So that being said, can you skip the message that tells you need Visual Studio and just continue on with the installation?  If you can't, then you may be in a bind, because I think that is the only development environment I've ever seen associated with the engine.